# moving File leads to file with path separator "/" in filename

Tags: java, macos, io

I try to move a file from one directory to another.
I do this with

```
File fileToMove = new File("/Users/kai-dj/separator_problem/from/file_to_move.file");
File destDir = new File("/Users/kai-dj/separator_problem/to");
if (fileToMove.exists() && destDir.isDirectory()) {
  fileToMove.renameTo(new File(destDir.getAbsolutePath()+File.pathSeparator+fileToMove.getName()));
}
```

I'd expect to find `file_to_move.file` in folder `/Users/kai-dj/separator_problem/to` after execution, but I get a file **named** `to/file_to_move.file` placed in the parent folder `/Users/kai-dj/separator_problem`. At least that's what Finder shows.

As I thought: "File names mustn't contain path separator characters, this can't be true.", I also checked what `ls` would output in terminal:

```
mac-book:separator_problem kai-dj$ ls
from        to:file_to_move.file
to
```

OK – seems no `/`in file name. Very strange nontheless.
Why does Finder show it as file name containing `/`?
Why does Java rename the file to `<dirname>:<filename>` – especially even when I used `File.pathSeparator`, not `/` and certainly not `:`?

I also tried with `Files.move` – same result.

***EDIT:*** Solved, but I'd still love to know, why Finder shows `:` as `/` ^^

Comment: "File.pathSeparator" is a colon. You may want to use a "File.separator" instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment above, the correct member to use is called `File.separator`.

Also, you can avoid using `File.separator` in general, and use `Paths` instead:

```
System.out.println(Paths.get("/Users/kai-dj/separator_problem/to", fileToMove.getName()).toAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: the other variant(maybe easier) is to use the two parameter constructor new File(parent, child)

Comment: And even easier - use `Paths`